# ¿Por que el puerto 465 no funciona para la conexión SMTP?

Tags: c#, smtp, puertos

Llevo un buen rato revisando la parte de controladores , modelos y cadena de conexión para saber si era un error de programación o en la parte de la conexión pero no , llegue a la conclusión de que puede ser el puerto que estoy utilizando y me recomendaron el 465 por que es el mejor para conexiones SMTP luego lo cambie al puerto 25 , me funciono pero no es seguro pasar información por este puerto, solo quiero saber 2 cosas : 1) por que el puerto 465 no funciona y 2) ¿hay otros puertos seguros para conexiones SMTP?

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace EnviarCorreoElectronico
{
    public class Formulario
    {
        private readonly string Email = "example@gmail.com";
        private readonly string Password = "contradeprueba";
        public Formulario()
        {

        }
        public void sendMail(string mail, string text)
        {
            MailMessage c = new MailMessage();
            c.From = new MailAddress(Email);
            c.To.Add(Email);
            c.Subject = "Mensaje Dilan";
            c.Body = text;
            MailAddress ms = new MailAddress(Email);
            c.CC.Add(ms);
            SmtpClient s = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            s.Port = 465;
            s.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Email, Password);
            s.EnableSsl = true;
            s.Send(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiar el puerto
en lugar de:

```
s.Port = 567;
```

Intenta ponerle:

```
s.Port = 587;
```

Si el problema persiste, verifica que tu cuenta de Google permite el acceso desde "aplicaciones menos seguras"

Puedes cambiar esa configuración aquí.
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: Gracias :DDDDDD